# How can I remove artifacts by Maven from the lib folder of the ear?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

How can I remove artifacts from the lib folder of the ear? For exemple: activation.jar.

I was try follow the especification about [Excluding a module](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/excluding-a-module.html) (just change webModule for jarModule) but without success with this error: `Artifact[jar:javax.activation:activation] is not a dependency of the project.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you need to use `provided` as the scope.  If the jars you need to remove are not dependencies of your project directly (ie are *transient* dependencies), then you need to exclude them from whatever is bringing them into your build .  If you actually need those classes at compile-time, you'll have to re-include them as `provided`:

```
    <dependency>
        <!-- this dependency has javax.activation as a dependency -->
        <groupId>blah.groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>blah.artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>blah.version</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only necessary if this jar is needed at compile-time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for answers, I got it just using <exclusions> without use <scope> because as you whote: "If the jars you need to remove are not dependencies of your project directly (ie are transient dependencies), then you need to exclude them..."

Comment: Yes, you'll only need to re-import as `provided` if you actually need the classes in that dependency at compile-time.  Otherwise just leave it out completely.

Answer (score 1):

Use `provided` as scope wherever the dependency is defined.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `scope` to `provided`. Maven will still add the dependency to the compile time classpath but not to the final WAR.